# Old version of Mediawiki 1.17; PHP version not supported

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have a very old version of a mediawiki. Version: 1.17. I think that it ran on php 5.2 or maybe 5.4. The web hoster has dropped the support for lower versions of php and provides now only support for PHP 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, ... Well that killed that old mediawiki.

Whenever I try to access the URL of the wiki, I get only a page with the following response:

```
PHP version not supported. 
The requested PHP version is not supported on this server.
```

I am not interested in updating the mediawiki to the latest version and using it on. All I want is a last access to save some "text".

Is there any way to change the "requested" PHP version in a configuration file of mediawiki? Maybe change it from  PHP 5.2.3 to 5.6?

I have checked /LocalSettings.php and /includes/DefaultSettings.php but I am not sure If I could change anything there that would solve the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

edit: here is a listing of campatibility: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Compatibility

Comment: This error message is being displayed by your hosting provider, not by PHP or MediaWiki. Contact your host for support.

Comment: they would not be able to help. They warned their users that support for php 5.2 is being dropped.

Answer (score 1):

as you stated the problem is on the web host side the options, even on the mediawiki documentations says tells you to sure to check your PHP installation and contact your host if it runs an outdated PHP version.
Users of version 1.17 version are advised to upgrade to version 1.32.0 (latest stable).

I think you have two options first one is maybe you can get a backup of the database and run it on a localserver with the php version needed and the second one is to get a manual upgrade to a version your server supports.

Anyway heres a step by step way to upgrade manually your mediawiki to the 1.2 version.
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading

But just make sure you have all the requirements:

MediaWiki 1.32 requires:

> PHP 7.0.13+
>
> One of the following:
>
> MySQL 5.5.8+ (or equivalent MariaDB)
>
> PostgreSQL 9.2+
>
> SQLite 3.3.7+
>
> Oracle 9.0.1+

Comment: I had the same 2 ideas. But I would rather just be able to change 1 line of code in the wiki configuration. Change from php 5.2 to 5.6.